# Events Module issue in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

Just started node.js and having this error while playing with events module.

TypeError: Cannot read property 'on' of undefined

```
const event = require('events').EventEmitter();
event.on('myevent', (msg)=>{
    for(var i = 0; i < 3; i++){
        console.log(`Message is: ${msg}`);        
    }    
});
event.emit('myevent', 'All is fine');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve your problem you need to instantiate the event obj.

for example:

```
const events = require('events');
const event = new events.EventEmitter();
```

now rest code will work!